# Instead of 404 error, displaying special symbols while i try to view the pdf which is not available in server

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I try to view the pdf file through url, but the pdf file is not available in the server directory. when i access the unavailable pdf document through url, it seems special symbols are loading in my browser instead of generating 404 Not Found error.

Please sort out my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What dou you mean by __"special symbols are loading in my browser"__

Comment: Thanks for your comment Axel. special symbols is some wired characters are showing in my browser and it's take more time to load and it cases my system halt. i'm using ubuntu 11.10